# Fetching encoder value with SimpleMotion library by Granite Devices

Tags: servomotor

Is it possible to fetch the current encoder position of a drive with the old SimpleMotion library (not V2) and a Granite Devices VSD-E through the `smRawCommand(...)` function?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the SimpleMotion library files yet? You can get them from [here](https://granitedevices.com/assets/files/simplemotion-latest.zip).

Please note that the old version for SimpleMotion is not supported anymore.

Comment: Please note if you want to promote your own product/blog you **must disclose your affiliation**, otherwise your answer may be flagged as spam. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Comment: If you are not affiliated with the site, I recommend you mention the fact to prevent flags.